# Confusion on particular step in this weak induction proof

Tags: logic, proof-verification, induction

I am studying for a midterm, and I came across this proof.

Use mathematical induction(weak) to show that for all integers n $\geq$ 2 , if x$_{1}$, x$_{2}$, ... x$_{n}$ are strictly between 0 and 1 then the following holds true.

(1-x$_{1}$)(1-x$_{2}$)...(1-x$_{n}$) $\geq$ 1-x$_{1}$-x$_{2}$-...-x$_{n}$

This is a screen shot of the parts of the the part I am having trouble understanding.
[image: This is the Professors proof]

My question is, why in the last step could it be assumed that x$_{n}$ is less than x$_{n}$(x$_{1}$ + x$_{2}$ +...+ x$_{n-1}$)? The rest of the proof seems self explanatory.

Comment: I don't think that inequality needs to hold. Furthermore, even if it's true, it helps very little. It is already know that $$x_n\left(x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_{n-1}\right)>0,$$ so $$\left(1-x_1-\ldots -x_n\right)+x_n\left(x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_{n-1}\right)>1-x_1-\ldots -x_n,$$ as desired.

Comment: The last step is wrong. Instead, take that last expression and strike out the $+ x_n$. Then it is mathematically sound and also shows what you want it to show

Comment: Just a typo. Probably did cut and paste and pasted too much.

Comment: Infinite thanks GitGud. I see what your saying. The original right side of the expression is inherently less than that same expression plus x$_{n}$(x$_{1}$ + x$_{2}$ +...+x$_{n-1}$) which must then be less then the original right side of the expression. I have a midterm tomorrow and I was tearing my hair out trying to understand what that x$_{n}$ was doing.

Comment: @GitGud Your comment would make a good answer.